# In Oozie, how can I redirect the output of a query to a file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, hue

In Oozie, I have used Hive action in Hue. and I want to redirect the output of the query to a file. How can I generate those file?

My HQL is :
select * from emptable 
where day>=${fromdate}  and day<=${todate}

My HiveServer Action contains:
a. HQL script
b. Two parameters options one for each dates like as fromdate = , todate =
c. Added file hive-site.xml.

My question is how can I redirect the output of a query to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to execute the Shell action which is not recommended, a better solution might be to do a

> INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path' SELECT * FROM TABLE

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified as : INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/path' SELECT aCol, '\t', bCol FROM TABLE. it provide TAB separated data, which is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Another Alternate option is by creating external Table in Hive,
Example

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name(col type,col2 type) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION '/path';
```

EXTERNAL table points to any HDFS location for its storage, rather than being stored in a folder specified by the configuration property hive.metastore.warehouse.dir